# Active Member in Period

Tags: mysql

I have a table as detailed below. I am trying to build a report on our internal portal (using PHP).  I need to be able to choose a date and it then gives information on how many active subscribers were live at the start of the period.

The user will select a month (always the first of the month). My issue seems to be it will include people who have cancelled back in July. How do i make it so that once that person has cancelled they don't appear in the output?  I'm hoping it can be done in SQL vs having to make something in PHP.

```
select * FROM group_assigned_users 
        where gau_regdate < '2016/10/01'  and (gau_cancelleddate <  '2016/10/01' or gau_cancelleddate = '0000-00-00')
        and  gau_group_id = 26 


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `group_assigned_users` (
  `gau_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Primary Key',
   `gau_status` enum('Pending','Active','Suspended','Terminated','Cancelled','Froze') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Pending',
  `gau_regdate` date NOT NULL,
  `gau_expirydate` date NOT NULL,
  `gau_nextdue` date NOT NULL,
  `gau_cancelleddate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gau_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7746 ;


INSERT INTO `group_assigned_users` (`gau_id`, `gau_status`, `gau_regdate`, `gau_expirydate`, `gau_nextdue`, `gau_cancelleddate`) VALUES
(2007, 'Active', '2007-01-10', '2017-06-26', '2017-06-26', '0000-00-00'),
(2020, 'Cancelled', '2007-12-19', '2015-12-19', '2016-12-19', '2015-12-17'),
(2044, 'Cancelled', '2007-09-26', '2014-05-27', '2014-05-27', '2014-05-27'),
(4824, 'Cancelled', '2010-08-26', '2011-08-26', '2011-08-26', '2011-08-26'),
(6520, 'Cancelled', '2013-06-19', '2015-07-16', '2015-07-16', '2015-07-16'),
(6680, 'Cancelled', '2013-09-26', '2016-06-26', '2016-06-26', '2016-01-19'),
(7058, 'Cancelled', '2014-11-07', '2015-12-10', '2015-12-10', '2015-09-25'),
(7066, 'Cancelled', '2014-11-14', '2015-11-20', '2016-11-20', '2015-11-19'),
(7174, 'Cancelled', '2015-04-22', '2016-05-20', '2016-05-20', '2016-02-16'),
(7191, 'Cancelled', '2015-05-17', '2015-12-04', '2015-12-04', '2015-10-07'),
(7372, 'Cancelled', '2015-10-11', '2016-10-11', '2016-10-11', '2016-02-19'),
(7389, 'Active', '2015-11-01', '2016-11-01', '2016-10-18', '0000-00-00'),
(7404, 'Cancelled', '2015-03-06', '2016-03-06', '2017-03-06', '2016-03-09'),
(7419, 'Active', '2015-11-04', '2016-11-04', '2016-11-04', '0000-00-00'),
(7422, 'Active', '2019-11-30', '2020-11-30', '2020-11-03', '0000-00-00'),
(7431, 'Cancelled', '2015-12-03', '2016-12-03', '2016-11-23', '2016-07-07'),
(7465, 'Cancelled', '2016-01-03', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-03', '2016-02-22'),
(7491, 'Cancelled', '2016-01-29', '2017-01-29', '2017-01-29', '2016-06-13'),
(7549, 'Active', '2016-03-09', '2017-03-09', '2017-03-01', '0000-00-00'),
(7595, 'Active', '2016-04-05', '2017-04-05', '2017-04-05', '0000-00-00'),
(7616, 'Active', '2016-05-04', '2017-05-04', '2017-04-27', '0000-00-00'),
(7627, 'Active', '2016-05-15', '2017-05-15', '2017-05-15', '0000-00-00'),
(7650, 'Active', '2016-06-01', '2017-06-01', '2017-06-08', '0000-00-00'),
(7684, 'Active', '2016-07-25', '2017-07-24', '2017-07-24', '0000-00-00'),
(7689, 'Active', '2016-08-02', '2017-08-02', '2016-11-01', '0000-00-00'),
(7691, 'Suspended', '2016-08-03', '2017-08-08', '2016-11-08', '0000-00-00'),
(7698, 'Active', '2016-08-10', '2017-02-11', '2017-02-11', '0000-00-00'),
(7715, 'Active', '2016-08-25', '2017-09-08', '2017-09-08', '0000-00-00'),
(7716, 'Active', '2016-08-25', '2017-02-08', '2017-02-08', '0000-00-00');
```

Comment: *…how many active subscribers were live at the start of the period.* – Please define "live".

Comment: Your request `select * FROM group_assigned_users where gau_regdate < '2016/10/01'  and (gau_cancelleddate <  '2016/10/01' or gau_cancelleddate = '0000-00-00');` looks correct, why do you think that it does not work?

Comment: Because if we choose October 2016 as the period... Its including people who cancelled in Feb but these people wouldn't be active in October which is the period Im running the report.